# What is the use of adding Apple ID to the System Preferences in Mac OS X 10.10 on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: icloud, system-preferences

In iCloud, you will have the ability to sync stuff from your Mac to the cloud.

In iTunes, you can use it to buy music etc…

In AppStore, it can be used for purchasing Apps

How about in System Preferences in Admin Account (attaching that ID to the Mac), what’s the purpose and use of it?

Answer (score 0):

To perform the following you need to link your Apple ID in system preferences:

1. Share files with others on your network
2. Share your screen with other computer users

Comment: I see, thank you for the reply. So if im not into Sharing Screens or Sharing Files, is it okay not to have an Apple ID there? If I just left it empty, no ID associated with my Macbook Pro, will it not affect me in any ways?